# Using on hover and out focus

Tags: jquery

I have a button and i want it to show a dropdown when hovered over and hide the dropdown again when foucout triggers. But it doesn't work. The "off" hover effect triggers even if i don't want it to do that before the focusout is triggerd. How can i do this?

```
$("#projectStatus").hover(function () {

    $("#projectStatusDrp").show();
});

$("#projectStatus").focusout(function () {
    $("#projectStatusDrp").hide();
});
```

//EDIT

This is what i want but it doesn't work either.

```
$("#projectStatus").hover(
    function() {
        $("#projectStatusDrp").show();
    }.blur(function() {
        $("#projectStatusDrp").hide();
    });
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `.hover(...` instead of `.focus(...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
      $("#projectStatus").mouseover(function(){

                $("#projectStatusDrp").show();
        );

      $("#projectStatus").blur(function() {
                $("#projectStatusDrp").hide();
        });
```

Also:

```
      $(document).click(function() {
                $("#projectStatusDrp").hide();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do, I hope

```
$("#projectStatus").hover(
    function(){
        $("#projectStatusDrp").show();
    ),        
    function() {
        $("#projectStatusDrp").hide();
    }
);
```

Check the [jQuery hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function for more.

Answer (score 0):

To do as you describe your code should be like this:

```
  $("#projectStatus").hover(function() {
     $("#projectStatusDrp").show();
 }).blur(function() {
     $("#projectStatusDrp").hide();
 });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mab8k5du/)

but hovering doesn't focus the element so your blur will never fire unless the user tabs to your element.

You could explicitly focus the element on hover like this:

```
 $("#projectStatus").hover(function() {
         $(this).focus();
         $("#projectStatusDrp").show();
     }).blur(function() {
         $("#projectStatusDrp").hide();
 })
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mab8k5du/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `hover` function from jQuery like so:

```
$("#projectStatus").hover(
function () {    
    $("#projectStatusDrp").show();
}, 
function () {
    $("#projectStatusDrp").hide();
});
```

The `hover` function takes in two functions as arguments, one for the when you hover in and when hover out. jQuery provides excellent documentation of it [here](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).